# Google Analytics Custom Dimensions command location

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I registered my MVC site on GA, sending in bunch of Ga commands to register the click events, with different labels.
I also want to send 2 different dimensions for 2 different User types - value1 & value2.

Am i doing this right in passing 2 custom dimensions for each click in Layout page like in the following code?

```
$("#lnk_Export").on("click", function () {
                if (('@(currUserType)') == 'value1')
                { ga('set', 'dimension1', '@(currUserType)'); }
                else if (('@(currUserType)') == 'value2')
                { ga('set', 'dimension2', '@(currUserType)'); }
                ga('send', 'event', 'link', 'click', 'Export to Excel');
            });
```

Above is an example for 1 click. I have 15 more clicks that i am sending and adding the 2 custom dimensions into each clicks.

Basically i want GA to show: 
User Type "value1" clicked link1 and link2
User Type "value2" clicked link5 and link8

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is that the custom dimension has hit scope. Then you can see in Analytics how many event labels have that particular custom dimension. However you can't have both in the same report, because the custom dimension being at the hit level, an event can have one or the other but can never have both.

Comment: Sending 2 dimesions are ok for each click? we did create 2 dimensions, each with a hit scope. some of the reports take a while to come through on GA.

Comment: Not in the same report, because being at the hit level, an event can have one or the other but can never have both.